# How are protocols used encoded in the data send over them?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, network-protocols, application-layer

I was reading answers to this [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614318/do-firewalls-block-non-http-traffic-on-port-80) explaining how the firewall will take certain actions dependent on the protocol data was sent over (such as FTP vs HTTP, etc.). In addition, the router will have the data rerouted differently dependent on whether it is UDP port X or TCP port X.

1) Is there a standard for encoding what protocol data was sent over in the data itself?

2) Are the protocols for all layers (1-7 in the OSI model) encoded in the message, or just certain layers such as transport layer and application layer?

Comment: (1) No; (2) no; (3) the OSI model does not apply to TCP/IP; (4) off topic.

Comment: @user207421 If there is no standard, how can the protocol that the client uses be determined?

Comment: The protocol is associated with the port number.

Comment: "_the router will have the data rerouted differently dependent on whether it is UDP port X or TCP port X._" Routers route packets based on the destination layer-3 address and its match in the routing table, not on the transport protocol address, which is not in the routing table.